# opencv2 sources missing on code.ros.org?

Tags: ros, vision-opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I was trying to get the source for opencv2 from:

[https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/vision_opencv/trunk/opencv2](http://https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/vision_opencv/trunk/opencv2)

but it seems to missing most of the files.  The only files that appear at the above location are:

```
Makefile
conf.py
cvbridge_python.rst
flann.patch
index.rst
mainpage.dox
manifest.xml
opencv2-python-link.patch
pythontest.patch
rosdoc.yaml
```

I poked around some of the tags as well but they all end up with this kind of short file list.  Has the source been moved somewhere?  Or am I just missing something obvious.

Thanks!
patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9960/opencv2-sources-missing-on-code.ros.org?/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2011-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Patrick,

Source for OpenCV library can be found [here](https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/branches/2.2/opencv). What your link points to is the ROS wrapper which checks out the code from above location at build time.

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2011-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-05-16**:
A good first step when  you find a package that doesn't contain what you expect is to check it's Makefile(s) and CMakeLists.txt. For example, you can see from the OpenCV Makefile that it is using the svn_checkout.mk script (which is documented on the wiki somewhere).

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-05-15**:
Ah ha!  Thanks!